# How load balancer works with asp.net session

Tags: asp.net, session, load-balancing

I have a project that's working but it needs to be scaled up to multiple servers. Management is considering default IIS load balancing (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129389.aspx)

Does this load balancer support sticky session (couldn't find it in documentation), and what are the ways to avoid issues with a project that heavily relies on session to store user data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your sessionstate in your database. This way it can be used acros different serves

Here is an msdn article on this topic: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

and another one i found:
http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3595766/Storing-Session-State-in-a-SQL-Server-Database.htm

Comment: Thanks, but that would require rewriting most of the application. Are you saying that it doesn't support "sticky sessions"? Meaning I can't configure it to send requests from the same machine to the same server every time?

Comment: Not sure if this can but you will put a lot of load on your server if you have a lot of trafic and are keeping all the sessionstates in memory. To implement database storage of your sessionstate you are not required to make a lot of changes to your code base, just implement the database storage option for your sessionstate.